# Are there folk terms for "spider"?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

I was remarking that the French word for spider, *araignée*, seems awfully technical and cumbersome compared to "spider". I'm sure native speakers don't perceive it as such, but to me it only suggests its etymology in *arachnid*, which is for us a purely technical, unevocative term.

In contrast, *spider* comes from *spinther*, i.e. "one that spins". We also have the (archaic) *lob* "lumpy thing" and *(atter)cob* "poison-head", still visible in the modern *cobweb*.

Does French have any terms that evoke a more poetic, descriptive sense of what spiders are and do? Or is the French cultural image of spiders so different from the role they played in English culture?

Comment: ...that said, the ultimate [etymology of *araignée*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CF%81%CE%AC%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%B7?tableofcontents=0), in Greek ἀράχνη "thread-knotter", is pretty good!

Comment: There's a  horror movie called Arachnid.

Comment: @Lambie Interesting point. Somehow it is more horrible than "Spider" would have been. I wonder why -- Phonology? Morphology? Foreignness (not that it's foreign, but it feels unEnglish)?

Comment: *Charlotte*!.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Arachnide* or the rarer *araneïde* are the technical and unevocative words in French for a spider.

*Araignée* doesn't sound at all technical or cumbersome. I don't think we have any established alternate poetic and descriptive term to name them outside maybe *la tisseuse*. There is also the very archaic *aragne*.

Comment: Thanks! The contrast between an etymologically transparent word and an even more etymologically transparent word is one I shouldn't underestimate. And would you say "la tisseuse" is purely poetic/literary or could one use it in conversation?

Comment: @LukeSawczak I wouldn't use *la tisseuse* in a conversation.

Comment: @jlliagre, not either [j'ai envie de tisser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK9BsXh73Lc) (1:45).

Answer (score 2):

*Araignée* is a very basic term for spider, as can be evidenced by its use in children's books, e.g., [*Chloé l'araignée*](https://www.gallimard-jeunesse.fr/9782075074292/chloe-l-araignee.html). I do agree that it is not an obviously simple one for non-French speakers... but as a non-English speaker I could add that *elephant* also seems rather technical to me, yet it is casually used in English (also *rhinoceros* and *hippopotamus* - but here one could say *rhino* and *hippo*).

Comment: It's certainly true that you can't gauge the perceived complexity or arcaneness of a word from the outside. Even the fact that every kid knows the four-syllable, Spanish-derived "alligator"...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Not sure about alligators, but definitely [crocodiles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1T9b0cax6s4)